# Is there any system table in redshift that gives me all properties of Library objects that i have created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, system-views

I have created Library object in my Redshift database using below code. Now I want to see in the system tables where all my library properties are saved\stored.

```sql
CREATE LIBRARY F_URLPARSE
LANGUAGE PLPYTHONU
FROM 'xxxxx'
CREDENTIALS 'xxxxx'
REGION AS 'xxx';
```

PS:Just assume `xxx` are my properties, here I am not mentioned due to privacy issue.

So when I am using `PG_LIBRARY` system view, I can only get the name of my object but no properties.

```
select * from pg_library;

name       | language_oid | file_store_id | owner
f_urlparse |       108254 |          2000 |   100
```

Finally, I need to get my library properties that I have given in script

```
FROM 'xxxxx'
CREDENTIALS 'xxxxx'
REGION AS 'xxx'
```

Please any one can help me to look at my library properties in database?

Comment: Please edit your post to make it more readable. Specifically, the code snippets

Comment: @RX9 FYI, StackOverflow users with sufficient reputation have the ability to edit Questions and Answers, so feel free to edit questions if you see a way to improve them. It helps the whole community and shows new users what is possible. Cheers!